# Dialog close went to previous page

Tags: jquery-mobile

Expected Scenario: I have two div in one page one is popup and other is the main page. When I click on popup popup should open and when i click close on pop up it should show the other div

Actual Scenario: WHen I close it doesnot show the other div instead it goes to the previous page 
Using Jquery Mobile 1.3.0

```
$.mobile.changePage("#publishlogonmanage", { role: "dialog", transition:"slideup",reload:false,reverse: false,changeHash: false });
```

PopUP COde

```
        <div data-role="page" id="publishlogonmanage" data-history="false" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b">        
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">        
        <a data-icon="delete" id="logonClose" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left"></a>       
        <a data-icon="delete"  data-theme="a" data-transition="flip" data-rel="back" data-mini="true" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" style="width:80px;" >Close</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #FFFFFF;">
    This is Body
    </div>

</div>
```

Main Page:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="MobilePage" data-overlay-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="a">
                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;"> <a href="javascript:GoBack();" data-icon="back" id="btnBack" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Back</a></div>

                <h1 id="title">                10            </h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="master-wrapper-page">
    This is body
     <div style="margin-top:7px;display:none;float: right !important; margin-left: 0px !important;overflow:ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;" data-close-btn="right" id="ManageLogon" data-mini="true" onclick="LoadDialog();" data-rel="popup"></div><img src="../../../images/logon-E.png" style="1px solid #666666;margin-top:3px;margin-right:-5px float: right;height:30px;width:30px;" id="logonexp" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using this awkward markup. if you want to open a popup why dont you use the popup widget?  Anyway .. is page with the id "MobilePage" also a dialog / popup?

Comment: No its not a dialog/popup